# How to read the toggel of input pin using python

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I have a python script which have a pyqt5 Gui and I want in this Gui to know if a certain pin is toggeld.
I did use

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.RISING, callback = change, bouncetime=3)
def change(channel):
    channel_is_on =GPIO.input(channel)
    print(channel_is_on)
```

so what I received after I hooked the jumper was always 1 even I didn't turn it on.
first how can I read just the toggle when it happen?
what is the problem that the pin read high when it been hooked up?

Answer (score 1):

The callback is only set up for rising edges. Change it to wait for both edges.

Comment: may be it's the solution but I still get the 1s after hooking the jumper , therefore I cannot confirm it

Comment: What is connected to the GPIO?  If nothing is connected it will randomly return 0 or 1.  Add a pull.

Comment: I do actually connect it to pulse generator. I used Pull down resistance and it worked and but even that I'm using the GPIO.BOTH it return just 0  have you an idea how can solve it

Comment: No.  You need to add all clarifications to your question.  It is almost always a mistake to read a GPIO level in a callback.